Looking for this horror anthology from the early 90s
From what I remember, the each episode starts off with a "monster" family sitting on the couch eating humans as snacks and watching TV which airs the actual episode.
One episode I remember involves two burglars breaking into a house and killing the old woman who lives there. On one of the burglar's hand, the old woman's face shows up and they try to get rid of it. At the very end I think, the face is transferred to one of their backs.

The show was called Monsters.  (IMDb Reference) (Wikipedia Reference)
The episode you cite sounds like Season 2, Episode 1 (25 Overall).  The episode was called "The Face".
